# Nginx does not Read Symbolic Linked Files?

Tags: nginx

Nginx was installed from Repository. Initially, it was working fine. However, I un linked default conf file in *sites-enabled* and added new virtual hosts file in *sites-available* folder and linked it using *ln -s*. *nginx -t* passes after restarting but it does not listen on port 80.

However if i copy the actual virtual hosts file in *sites-enabled* folder. After restart,it works once again. On a side note, same happens for *default* virtual hosts file. Here is the out put of *ls -lR* for nginx diretory

```
.:
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  3 03:38 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  898 Nov  3 03:06 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2258 Nov  3 03:06 koi-utf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1805 Nov  3 03:06 koi-win
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2085 Nov  3 03:06 mime.types
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5287 Nov  3 03:06 naxsi_core.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  287 Nov  3 03:06 naxsi.rules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2123 Dec 30 17:16 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  131 Nov  3 03:06 proxy_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  465 Nov  3 03:06 scgi_params
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 30 17:29 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 30 17:29 sites-enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  532 Nov  3 03:06 uwsgi_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3071 Nov  3 03:06 win-utf

./conf.d:
total 0

./sites-available:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Dec 30 17:29 default

./sites-enabled:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Dec 30 17:29 default -> sites-available/default
```

Comment: Please post the output of 'ls -lR /etc/nginx' command

Comment: kindly see the directory listing of nginx, i guess it has to do something with _default_ file permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are fine, but symbolic link is broken -- it should point to `../sites-available/default`

Comment: thanks, my bad.  i also got it figured by comparing the directory listing output of default installation and my way of linking files :)